# An Error occurred fetching comments

Tags: bug, comments

An Error occurred fetching comments

Why this happens? is this a known bug or a well defined behavior?

It would be great if someone can confirm if this a message from a handled exception.

As a user who for the first time saw this message, my first impression was something is wrong with the SO system(Some server down).

Comment: I was going to include a screen shot but cannot see the message anymore. It was there under my question for 5 minutes.

Comment: The Error had a red background.

Comment: You should try to reload the page, that will load all new comments also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get "An error occurred fetching comments", it's most likely that the post was already deleted when you click "show N more comments".